# 「レビュー|再オープン票」の説明にバグあり

Tags: バグ, 完了, ハイパーリンク

「レビュー|再オープン票」の説明で$siteName$と変数が変換されないまま残ってしまっている。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

修正されていることを確認しました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]